# Django - PasswordChangeForm sin contraseña anterior (without Old Password)

Tags: python, django

me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de que el usuario no tenga que colocar su contraseña anterior para cambiar su contraseña mientras está logueado:

Le coloqué un required False en el forms.py, pero igualmente no funciona... Les muestro lo que tengo:

forms.py

```
class MyPasswordChangeForm(PasswordChangeForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["old_password"] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}), required=False)
        self.fields["new_password1"].widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"})
        self.fields["new_password2"].widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"})
```

views.py

```
class ChangePasswordView(SuccessMessageMixin, PasswordChangeView):

    form_class = MyPasswordChangeForm
    template_name = 'change-password.html'
```

Al hacer esto y sacar de alguna manera ese campo(old_password) me aparece el siguiente error:
"Your old password was entered incorrectly. Please enter it again."

Hay alguna manera de evitarlo?

Answer (score 0):

dos cosas.

- Primero que nada creo que **esto implica un riesgo grave de seguridad**, si dejas
  tu sesión abierta te podrían cambiar la contraseña.
- Segundo, falta un poco de contexto en la pregunta (versión de Django,
  algunos imports, el mixin que estás usando, etc.)

En fin, si de todas formas a alguien le ayuda esto funcionaría para la mayoría de las versiones de Django (*no ha cambiado desde 2016*)

Si vemos el código de Django de [*PasswordChangeForm*](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5cc9464e4d8fe2762e462560665fd1f28104bbca/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L398) podemos observar que todo lo implementado ahí es precisamente para validar la *vieja contraseña*.

Así que haría más sentido implementar el formulario del que ésta clase está heredando: [*SetPasswordForm*](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5cc9464e4d8fe2762e462560665fd1f28104bbca/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L353). Ese formulario no incluye la validación de vieja contraseña.

Y podrías implementar una vista con ese formulario:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import SetPasswordForm
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordChangeView

class ChangePasswordView(PasswordChangeView):

    form_class = SetPasswordForm
    template_name = "change-password.html"
```

Eso sí, tu nuevo template *change-password.html* no debería incluir ninguna referencia a *form.old_password*

Saludos, espero te sirva. Y repito, esto implica un riesgo grave de seguridad.